# If you're a Moon druid with a level of exhaustion, and then Wild Shape into an elemental, do you regain this exhaustion when you revert?

Tags: dnd-5e, druid, conditions, wild-shape, elementals

Say you're a Circle of the Moon druid, and you have at least 1 level of exhaustion. You then use Wild Shape to transform into an elemental.

Since elementals are immune to exhaustion, you would obviously not have exhaustion while you were in elemental form. But when you revert to normal form, would your level(s) of exhaustion come back? Or would your exhaustion remain gone?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Comment: See also: [Is an Immune creature considered to have the condition without suffering its effects?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/161270/is-an-immune-creature-considered-to-have-the-condition-without-suffering-its-eff)

Answer (score 7):

## No Rule, Suppression Advised

Jeremy Crawford, lead rules designer for D&D [points out that the books don't contain a rule about when a spell target becomes invalid](https://twitter.com/jeremyecrawford/status/931621590730653696), while not a spell I believe there is a similar hole in rules for targets of other features as well. His advice is that it is suppressed while the target is invalid, and returns if they become valid again.

> There's no rule governing what happens when a valid spell target temporarily becomes an invalid target. A good rule of thumb is that the spell is suppressed while the target is invalid. #DnD

This treatment of the rules makes logical sense, because the [exhaustion](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/appendix-a-conditions#Exhaustion) would should only end with a night rest with food and drink.

Comment: The SAC has a bit on the *heroism* spell you could potentially use as it's a similar situation: "The heroism spell would suppress a frightening effect that was already on its target. When the spell ends, the target’s immunity goes away and the frightening effect resumes if it has not expired or been removed."

Comment: It makes sense from a narrative point of view to supress it as well: Jordan was feeling exhausted after the last battle so when the fire nation attacked he wild shaped into a being that physically cannot be exhausted. As his own body reformed the aching muscles and lack of energy returned.